# C# and the mischief of floats

Tags: c#, floating-point, rounding

In testing as to why my program is not working as intended, I tried typing the calculations that seem to be failing into the immediate window.

```
Math.Floor(1.0f)
1.0 - correct
```

However:

```
200f * 0.005f
1.0

Math.Floor(200f * 0.005f)
0.0 - incorrect
```

Furthermore:

```
(float)(200f * 0.005f)
1.0

Math.Floor((float)(200f * 0.005f))
0.0 - incorrect
```

Probably some float loss is occuring, 0.99963 ≠ 1.00127 for example.

I wouldn't mind storing less pricise values, but in a non lossy way, for example if there were a numeric type that stored values as integers do, but to only three decimal places, if it could be made performant.

I think probably there is a better way of calculating (n * 0.005f) in regards to such errors.

edit:

TY, a solution:

```
Math.Floor(200m * 0.005m)
```

Also, as I understand it, this would work if I didn't mind changing the 1/200 into 1/256:

```
Math.Floor(200f * 0.00390625f)
```

The solution I'm using. It's the closest I can get in my program and seems to work ok:

```
float x = ...;
UInt16 n = 200;
decimal d = 1m / n;
... = Math.Floor((decimal)x * d)
```

Comment: dude this problem has many duplicates in stackoverflow, use **decimal** type. Are you sure your question didn't match many existing questions?

Comment: Your "solution" is still wrong. You must use the `m` suffix, instead of casting a float constant to decimal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Floats represent numbers as *fractions with powers of two in the denominator*. That is, you can exactly represent 1/2, or 3/4, or 19/256. Since .005 is 1/200, and 200 is not a power of two, instead what you get for `0.005f` is the closest fraction that has a power of two on the bottom that can fit into a 32 bit float.

Decimals represent numbers as fractions with powers of ten in the denominator. Like floats, they introduce errors when you try to represent numbers that do not fit that pattern. `1m/333m` for example, will give you the closest number to 1/333 that has a power of ten as the denominator and 29 or fewer significant digits. Since 0.005 is 5/1000, and that is a power of ten, `0.005m` will give you an exact representation. The price you pay is that decimals are much larger and slower than floats.

You should always always always use decimals for financial calculations, never floats.

Comment: Hey Eric, while I agree that decimal is better than float for financial calculations, I have to say that I've encountered few cases where using double for financial calculations caused any problem. Excel comes to mind. I tried and failed to convince my ex boss to use decimal when we started our last project, and no disaster has resulted (partly because of changes in Turkish and Italian currency, no doubt). Do you know of any source to support the implication that the size and speed cost of decimals is always always always warranted for financial calculations?

Comment: I knew about the decimal type, but thought it was just a high precision float. I didn't realise that it worked like this. It's good to know.

Comment: I tend to use Int32 over int and Int16 over short, maybe float could also be float32_2, double as float64_2 and decimal as float128_10, just an idea :¬P

Comment: @phoog: It is entirely possible to use double for currency, as long as you truely understand that double is a base-2 float point number based on IEEE 754, and all that entails. Some results are surprising. For example, if `x` is a double, it is legal for `x!=x` to be true, even when `x` is not NaN. (This is due to the arules surounding extended precision.) It is very tricky to reason about doubles. Decimals tend be be easy to reason about, as rounding and exactness tend to match your intuition.

Comment: @phoog: Lastly it is rather rare for arithmatic on decimals to be the bottleneck in an application, so going with doubles because they are faster is premature optimization. Writing a forms-over-data GUI application in assembly because it is faster sounds absurd right? Well while that is an extreme case of premature opimization, the same basic logic should apply to this.

Comment: @alan2here: I once spent a couple of weeks adjusting a C# financial algorithm so that it would replicate the VB3 version we had ported. VB3 used single-precision floats, and in C# we were more accurate and used decimals. But the client noticed the values changed and the original calculations were the spec. The differences (when rounding to the closest multiple of `0.01`) were astounding.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that 0.005f is *actually* 0.004999999888241291046142578125... so less than 0.005. That's the closest `float` value to 0.005. When you multiply that by 200, you end up with something less than 1.

If you use `decimal` instead - all the time, *not* converting from `float` - you should be fine *in this particular scenario*. So:

```
decimal x = 0.005m;
decimal y = 200m;
decimal z = x * y;
Console.WriteLine(z == 1m); // True
```

However, don't assume that this means `decimal` has "infinite precision". It's still a floating point type with limited precision - it's just a floating *decimal* point type, so 0.005 is exactly representable.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot tolerate any floating point precision issues, use `decimal`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

Ultimately even `decimal` has precision issues (it allows for 28-29 significant digits). If you are working in it's supported range ((-7.9 x 10^28 to 7.9 x 10^28) / (100^28)), you are quite unlikely to be impacted by them.

Comment: I've just tried Math.Floor((decimal)(n * 0.005f)) and it seems to work. I can't see why, shouldn't (n * 0.005f) give an imprecise answer which is then converted into a higher precision float? Also Math.Floor creates a sharp cut off, why would (seemingly does) the extra precision help?

Comment: @alan2here: Work out what fraction that has a power of two in the denominator is closest to 0.005 if you are restricted to the 32 bits of a float. Now work out what fraction that has a power of two in the denominator is closest to 0.005 if you are restricted to the 64 bits of a decimal. **Is there some reason why the closest fractions in each case have to be both greater than or both less than 0.005**?

Comment: I hadn't seen your answer when I posted the reply comment.